# Login to administrator gui fails

Tags: greeter

I have an administrator account and user account.
My user account GUI works fine, but when I login to my administrator account the password is accepted and the screen goes to black as if it's logging in and then dumps back to the login screen.

I have confirmed the password is correct because this semi-login doesn't occur when I intentionally type the incorrect password, it shakes the password box and that's it.

I can login into the admin account through the console but it just fails to launch the GUI under the admin account.

Can anyone suggest the problem?

Comment: Did you run something like `sudo startx` before you noticed this? What was your last system-relevant action before the lock-out?

Comment: Make sure your administrator account has a profile folder in `/home/` and that the permissions and ownership of that folder are correct.

Comment: I have the same problem. Brand new install. This was my first attempt at logging in, and it won't stay logged in. p.s. I didn't just try it once, I'm just pointing out that I haven't done anything to the system yet.

Comment: When you say 'administrator' do you mean a user account you've created in group 'administrator' or are you trying to log into the GUI as 'root'